# Reset internet settings with no internet

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I am trying to get a master code to reset parental controls, but the 3ds does not have internet to send one. How do I get round this?
Plz help, im going mental...!!!

Comment: Something tells me you aren't going to be able to get around this without finding an internet connection...

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nintendo support](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/493/~/forgot-parental-controls-pin) you need to receive the code via email (which is where I suspect you're having issues).

That said, they do have an option for you to get it without an email, although there is a 50 cent charge that they require (to ensure it's done by an adult, because you pay by credit card, is the reasoning) to send you the code you need to unlock it. If you go to the bottom of the help page I linked, and where it asks "Was an e-mail configured for use with Parental Controls?", select "No, or not sure", and follow the steps - the last one is entering some information (an inquiry number they provide you) on a page where you also enter credit card info for the code.

This should then give you the code you need, without having to have it emailed to you.